# Not able to see the sound indicator in system notifications

Tags: sound, indicator-sound

This is what happened.

1. Skype used to crash continuously
2. I removed pulseaudio
3. Put gnome-alsamixer
4. The sound indicator stopped showing up
5. I uninstalled gnome-alsamixer
6. Made pulseaudio start again
7. I can use the sound now and I have no issues with skype anymore. May be the solution was something else
8. But I can not see sound indicator anymore. I have to use the volume keys or use the sound in systems menu.

How do I get it back? I know its in there somewhere and needs enabling. But not sure where or what? I will appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are referring to the sound indicator in Panel 0 (usually at the top)?  If so, see [Ubuntu launchpad bug #1208204](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1208204)

This has been observed by several users.  There is a patch in message #5 that I can confirm as working for me.  I suggest that you try the patch and reboot.  Does that bring the indicator item for audio control back into operations?

Note that the indicator-sound package containing the file needing the patch was just re-released yesterday without the patch (scheduling issue, probably).  I had to re-apply the patch.  So, keep an eye on your system updates.

Comment: Well, I realized that I hated Unity and gave up on it completely. Now I am using gnome 3 instead.

Comment: I had the same issue in Xubuntu (XFCE) so I suspect that you are likely to see it in Gnome too since XFCE and Gnome share a lot of desktop infrastructure.  Please reply back one way or the other to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Nope. The gnome is fine.